# Get current content from several posts in wp loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am unable to show single post on my popup.

**Below the code which i have tried :**

```
<div class="row homepage_blogs" data-masonry>
<?php
$i = 1;
$args = array(
    'category__in' => array(4), 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12 post_item_wrapper" >
            <div class="post animated zoom_in homepage_post" style="animation-delay: <?php (.4 * $i) ?>s">
                <h3 class="blog-tit lightbox"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <div class="blog-desc">
                    <p  class="lightbox"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200) . '[...]'; ?></p>
                    <a href="#" data-featherlight-close-icon="close" data-featherlight=".lightbox"><span class="popup-link">MORE</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    $i++;
endif; 
?>
```

When i click on "More" button it displays content of all the posts but i want only single post content using loop.

also i need to show whole content of post and not only exerpt.

any ideas how i can get only one?

thanks for help

Comment: Can you please show the full html code of this section before integrating to wordpress code?

Comment: i dont have one, i got this to work with.